# Using CountA or Equivelant on a range of columns contained within a larger array of columns

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am currently reading a range into an array to perform a few calculations before outputting into another worksheet. My reason for using the array is speed as I am often dealing with thousands of rows.

I have one particular calculation that I am struggling with for some reason.

This is the part I am struggling with (rest of sample of this code is further down):

```
For i = non_rev_rows To 2 Step -1.


**' Remove Blank Rows from array
    If data_range(i, 2) = "No WBS/CC" Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C" & i & ":M" & i)) = 0 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
```

So basically when a row in column 2 is equal to "No WBS/CC" then I need to run a CountA or any other method  you can recommend to calcuate the total value of columns C to M on that row. I am essentially looking for any row that = "No WBS/CC" and where columns C:M have no value. If so, then delete the entire row. If there is a value in columns C:M then I would not wish to delete the row.

```
'Row Count
With Sheets("array")
     non_rev_rows = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

' Remove Blank Rows from array
' Replace "NO WBS/CC" with Co Code Over-Ride if supplied
' Set Debit / Credit
' Round to 2 decimal places
Set data = array_sheet.Range("A1:M" & non_rev_rows)
data_range = data.Value

For i = non_rev_rows To 2 Step -1.


**' Remove Blank Rows from array
    If data_range(i, 2) = "No WBS/CC" Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C" & i & ":M" & i)) = 0 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
        
        ' Replace "NO WBS/CC" with Co Code Over-Ride if supplied
        If data_range(i, 13) <> 0 Then
            data_range(i, 2) = data_range(i, 13)
        End If
        
    End If**
    
' Set Debit / Credit
    data_range(i, 3) = Replace(data_range(i, 3), "Debit", 41)
    data_range(i, 3) = Replace(data_range(i, 3), "Credit", 51)
    
' Round to 2 decimal places
    data_range(i, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Round(data_range(i, 5), 2)
    
'    If data_range(i, 3) = "Debit" Then
'        data_range(i, 3).Value = 41
'    ElseIf data_range(i, 3) = "Credit" Then
'        data_range(i, 3).Value = 51
'    End If
    

    
   
    'data_range(i, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Range(data_range(i, 5)).Value, 2)
    'Range("E" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Range("E" & i).Value, 2)
    
Next i
```

```
**' Remove Blank Rows from array
    If data_range(i, 2) = "No WBS/CC" Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C" & i & ":M" & i)) = 0 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
```

This code does not result in an error but it also does not have the desired impact. I have several rows in my test data that contain "No WBS/CC" in column 2 and zero values in columns C:M but the code is not deleting those rows.

Comment: Let excel do the heavy lifting.  Filter the rows to get those that meet your criteria, create a union of the output range, transfer the union range to a VBA array.

Comment: I'd also recommend that you install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and take a look at the code inspections to start your education on not using default methods.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to filter anything. There are reasons for this as there are a lot of working components. Everything is read into the array. I also can't install addins as this is work based unfortunately and I am restricted in terms of what I can install.

Comment: Could you share the complete code? If not then at least the continuation, in particular the code that copies the array to a worksheet?

Comment: 'Paste completed data back into array tab:
data.Value = data_range

Comment: data.Value = data_range does work as all the other calculations I am performing on the array are reflected in the data that is output back. If you can think of any easier way to delete a row in the array where columns C:M are blank I am open to suggestions. I appreciate everyones help

Comment: You simply cannot delete an array row in the way you try. It is not impossible, but it will not be faster than in a range. If you only want learning, I can show it. Then, it looks that you do not understand simple VBA operations, no offence... You can use `data.Value = data_range` **only if the `data` range has the same number of rows and columns as the array**. If you try deleting rows from array, the above mentioned operation is not possible, anymore. Of course, in the way you try...

Comment: Whatever happened to *"before outputting into another worksheet"*? Are you trying to delete the rows in the worksheet and in the array, so you could use `data.Value = data_range` to write back? Please clarify. A screenshot of your worksheet would do wonders. Maybe best share a code without the use of an array so if it makes sense to use one, we could suggest a solution.

Comment: If your macro creation is a formal requirement of your work, getting Rubberduck installed should be an obvious win for those who control what can be installed.  If writing macros isn't a formal part of your role description, how do you justify what you are doing to your manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you want learning/understanding how an array row can be deleted (adapted for your case), please test the next way. It will return the array without deleted rows starting from "O2" of the same sheet, so the range after M:M column must be empty. You can easily adapt last code line to return wherever you need (in other sheet, other workbook...):

```
Sub DeleteArrayRows()
Dim array_sheet As Worksheet, non_rev_rows As Long, Data As Range, count2 As Long, data_range, arrRow, i As Long

Set array_sheet = ActiveSheet 'worksheets("array")
 non_rev_rows = array_sheet.Range("E" & array_sheet.rows.count).End(xlUp).row

Set Data = array_sheet.Range("A1:M" & non_rev_rows)
data_range = Data.Value

For i = 1 To UBound(data_range)
    count2 = 0
    If data_range(i, 2) = "No WBS/CC" Then
        With Application
            arrRow = .Transpose(.Transpose(.Index(data_range, i, 0))) 'extract a slice of the row array
        End With
        Debug.Print Join(arrRow, ""): Stop 'just to see the joinned respecitve slice In Immediate Window
                                           'comment it after seeing what it represents and press F5
        If data_range(i, 1) <> "" Then count2 = Len(data_range(i, 1))
        If Len(Join(arrRow, "")) - count2 = Len(data_range(i, 2)) Then
            data_range = DeleteArrayRow_(data_range, i):  i = i - 1
        End If
    End If
    If i = UBound(data_range) Then Exit For
Next i
'drop the array (without deleted rows) in a range:
array_sheet.Range("O1").Resize(UBound(data_range), UBound(data_range, 2)).Value = data_range
End Sub

Private Function DeleteArrayRow_(arr As Variant, RowToDelete As Long) As Variant 'interesting...
'It does not work to eliminate the first array row...
Dim Rws As Long, cols As String
Rws = UBound(arr) - LBound(arr)
cols = "A:" & Split(Columns(UBound(arr, 2) - LBound(arr, 2) + 1).address(, 0), ":")(0)

DeleteArrayRow_ = Application.Index(arr, Application.Transpose(Split(Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("Row(1:" & _
                (RowToDelete - 1) & ")"))) & " " & Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("Row(" & _
                (RowToDelete + 1) & ":" & UBound(arr) & ")"))))), Evaluate("COLUMN(" & cols & ")"))
End Function
```

It is not extremely fast, I tried showing it only for didactic purpose. To see that it is and how it is possible...

Note: I did not pay attention to all at the code lines after deletion. It can be easily adapted to include that part...

Answer (score 0):

You can do both tests on the array rather than partially in array and partially in the worksheet.
Only delete the row in the worksheet when you find a full match.

```
Public Sub Test2()

Dim data_range As Variant
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lColumns As Long
Dim lCounter As Long

data_range = Sheet1.Range("A1:M6")
' Add the data to an array

For lRows = UBound(data_range) To LBound(data_range) Step -1
'Step through the array in reverse
    If data_range(lRows, 2) = "No WBS/CC" Then
'Check for the "No WBS/CC" value in the second column of the array
        
        lCounter = 0
'Reset the counter

        For lColumns = 3 To 13
             If Not IsEmpty(data_range(lRows, lColumns)) Then
                lCounter = lCounter + 1
             End If
        Next lColumns
'Check columns in the array row to see if they have data
'Add to the counter for each cell having value
        
        If lCounter = 0 Then
            Sheet1.Rows(lRows).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
'If the counter is zero delete the current row in the Workbook

    End If
Next lRows


End Sub
```

Sample data before the macro is run.  The row we expected to be removed highlighted in green.

[image]

Sample data after the macro is run.  The expected row has been removed.

[image]

An alternate option is to write the valid rows to a new array.
Clear the data on the worksheet, then write the new array to the worksheet.

Comment: This looks exactly what I am after Robert. Thanks for that. Will test it out.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Rows

```vb
Sub DoStuff()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Array")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(LastRow, "M"))
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = rg.Columns.Count
    
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To rCount
        If Not IsRowBlank(Data, sr, 3, 13) Then ' is not blank
            ' Replace "NO WBS/CC" with Co Code Over-Ride if supplied
            If CStr(Data(sr, 1)) = "No WBS/CC" Then
                If Data(sr, 13) <> 0 Then
                    Data(sr, 2) = Data(sr, 13)
                End If
            End If
            ' Set Debit / Credit
            Data(sr, 3) = Replace(Data(sr, 3), "Debit", 41)
            Data(sr, 3) = Replace(Data(sr, 3), "Credit", 51)
            ' Round to 2 decimal places
            Data(sr, 5) = Application.Round(Data(sr, 5), 2)
            ' Copy source row to destination row.
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        'Else ' is blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Clear bottom source data.
    If dr < rCount Then
        For sr = dr + 1 To rCount
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(sr, c) = Empty
            Next c
        Next sr
    End If
                     
    rg.Value = dData

End Sub

Function IsRowBlank( _
    Data() As Variant, _
    ByVal DataRow As Long, _
    ByVal StartColumn As Long, _
    ByVal EndColumn As Long) _
As Boolean
    Dim c As Long
    For c = StartColumn To EndColumn
        If Len(CStr(Data(DataRow, c))) > 0 Then Exit For
    Next c
    IsRowBlank = c > EndColumn
End Function
```